# Grouping similar JSON values in android

Tags: android, json

I am retrieving JSON values from database to android.

The JSON is as below

```
"checkFreeArray":
 [
 {"checkPaid":"Free","locName":"Area 1"},
 {"checkPaid":"Paid","locName":"Area 2"},
 {"checkPaid":"Paid","locName":"Area 1"},
 {"checkPaid":"Free","locName":"Area 2"},
 {"checkPaid":"Free","locName":"Area 3"}
 ]
```

I want to sum up these data as

```
 (Area 1: 1 Paid,1 Free
  Area 2 : 1 Paid, 1 Free,
  Area 3: 1 Free)
```

in an ArrayList.

how to do in android?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fetch this data into a Json Array and can add condition to add element in new ArrayList like below.

```
JSONarray check=response.getJSonArray("checkFreeArray");
if(check!=null && check.length()>0){
for(int i=0;i<check.length();i++){
JsonObject json=check.getJsonObject(i);

if(json.getString("locName").equalsIgnoreCase("Area 1")){
                    if(json.getString("checkPaid").equalsIgnoreCase("free")){
                        loc_1_count_free++;
                    }
                    else{
                        loc_1_count_paid++;
                    }
                }
                else if(json.getString("locName").equalsIgnoreCase("Area 2")){
                    if(json.getString("checkPaid").equalsIgnoreCase("free")){
                        loc_2_free++;
                    }
                    else{
                        loc_2_paid++;
                    }

                }
                else if(json.getString("locName").equalsIgnoreCase("Area 3")){
                    if(json.getString("checkPaid").equalsIgnoreCase("free")){
                        loc_3_free_count++;
                    }
                    else{
                        loc_3_paid++;
                    }
                }

}
}
List<String> updated_array=new ArrayList<>();
        updated_array.add("Area 1:"+ loc_1_count_paid+" Paid, "+loc_1_count_free+" Free");
        updated_array.add("Area 2:"+ loc_2_paid+" Paid, "+loc_2_free+" Free");
        updated_array.add("Area 3:"+ loc_3_paid+" Paid, "+loc_3_free_count+" Free");
```

hope it helps.